# mocking hook with apollo client , react testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, graphql, apollo

i am trying to test a custom hook which is using subscribe to more of apollo client.
the custom hook is fetching events and it is connected with subscription to the subscribe to more apollo client option to add more events to the cached query result ( using apollo client type policy}
**Im receiving  the following error:**

```
  Expected variables: {"limit":10,"offset":0,"exclude":{"eventType":["LEAKAGE","WATCHMAN"]},"filter":{"shipId":<undefined>,"cameraId":<undefined>,"companyId":<undefined>,"fleetId":1,"withHidden":<undefined>}}
    
    Failed to match 1 mock for this query. The mocked response had the following variables:
      {"exclude":{"eventType":["WATCHMAN","LEAKAGE"]},"filter":{"fleetId":1,"shipId":1,"cameraId":1,"companyId":1,"withHidden":false},"limit":10,"offest":0,"withHidden":true}
```

here are the relevant files:

**the fetch events hook:**

```
export const useFetchShipEvents = ({
    limit,
    offset = 0,
    fleetId,
    shipId,
    cameraId,
    companyId,
    noExclude = false,
    withHidden,
}: IProps) => {
    const [shipEvents, setShipEvents] = useState<ShipEvents>();
    const [isEventsLoading, setIsEventsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [isEventsError, setIsEventsError] = useState<ApolloError>();
    const user = useReactiveVar(userStore.userAuth.authUser);
    console.log(' ~ file: fetchEvents.hooks.ts:34 ~ user:', user);
    const userAdmin = useReactiveVar(userStore.userAuth.userAdmin);

    let groupedShipIds = user?.attributes?.['custom:grouped_Shipid'];
    if (groupedShipIds) {
        groupedShipIds = JSON.parse(groupedShipIds);
    }

    const [fetchEvents, { subscribeToMore, loading, fetchMore }] = useLazyQuery<any, EventsPaginationInput>(
        queries.events,
        {
            variables: {
                limit,
                offset,
                exclude: noExclude
                    ? { eventType: [ShipEventType.WATCHMAN] }
                    : {
                            eventType: [ShipEventType.LEAKAGE, ShipEventType.WATCHMAN],
                      },
                filter: {
                    shipId,
                    cameraId,
                    companyId,
                    fleetId,
                    withHidden,
                },
            },
            fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
            partialRefetch: true,
            returnPartialData: true,

            onCompleted(data) {
                setShipEvents(data?.shipEvents);
            },

            onError(error) {
                console.error(error);
            },
        }
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!shipEvents && loading) {
            setIsEventsLoading(true);
        }
        return () => setIsEventsLoading(false);
    }, [loading]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (subscribeToMore && (fleetId || shipId || userAdmin)) {
            subscribeToMore({
                document: subscriptions.eventAdded,
                variables: {
                    fleetId,
                    shipId,
                    groupedShipIds: groupedShipIds,
                    exclude: { eventType: [ShipEventType.LEAKAGE, ShipEventType.WATCHMAN] },
                },
                updateQuery: (prev, { subscriptionData }) => {
                    if (!subscriptionData) return prev;
                    const event = subscriptionData.data.shipEventAdded;

                    const prevEventsArr = prev.shipEvents.events;
                    const isSome = prevEventsArr.some((prevEvents: ShipEvent) => prevEvents.id === event.id);

                    if (isSome) return;
                    return Object.assign({}, prev, {
                        shipEvents: { events: [event, ...prev.shipEvents.events], totalCount: prev.totalCount + 1 },
                    });
                },
            });
        }
    }, [subscribeToMore, fleetId, shipId, cameraId]);

    return { fetchEvents, shipEvents, isEventsLoading, fetchMore, subscribeToMore };
};
```

**the mock:**

```
export const shipEventsMockQuery = [
    {
        request: {
            query: GET_EVENTS,
            variables: {
                exclude: { eventType: ['WATCHMAN', 'LEAKAGE'] },
                filter: { fleetId: 1, shipId: 1, cameraId: 1, companyId: 1, withHidden: false },
                limit: 10,
                offest: 0,
                withHidden: true,
            },
        },
        result: {
            data: {
                shipEvents: {
                    events: [
                        {
                            burnedImage1Url: null,
                            burnedImage2Url: null,
                            burnedVodUrl: null,
                            camera: {
                                id: 1290,
                                shipId: 1,
                                shipCameraId: 4,
                                location: null,
                                description: null,
                                title: '4',
                            },
                            cameraId: 1290,
                            endTime: null,
                            eventState: 'NOT_ACKNOWLEDGED',
                            eventType: 'PPE_HELMET',
                            id: 58028,
                            image1Url: null,
                            image2Url: null,
                            isCameraDisabled: false,
                            lastPersonTime: null,
                            liveUrl: null,
                            notes: null,
                            recordingStartTime: null,
                            severity: 'INTERMEDIATE',
                            shipEventId: 423421342,
                            shipId: 1,
                            speed: null,
                            startTime: '2023-03-10T06:26:30.706Z',
                            vodHlsUrl: null,
                            vodPath: null,
                            __typename: 'ShipEvent',
                        },
                    ],
                    totalCount: 1,
                },
            },
        },
    },
];

export const shipEventsSubscriptionmock = [
    {
        request: {
            query: subscriptions.eventAdded,
            variables: {
                exclude: { eventType: ['WATCHMAN', 'LEAKAGE'] },
                shipId: 1,
                fleedId: 1,
                groupedShipIds: [1, 2],
                withHidden: true,
            },
        },
        result: {
            data: {
                eventAdded: [
                    {
                        burnedImage1Url: null,
                        burnedImage2Url: null,
                        burnedVodUrl: null,
                        camera: {
                            id: 1290,
                            shipId: 1,
                            shipCameraId: 4,
                            location: null,
                            description: null,
                            title: '4',
                        },
                        cameraId: 1290,
                        endTime: null,
                        eventState: 'NOT_ACKNOWLEDGED',
                        eventType: 'PPE_HELMET',
                        id: 58028,
                        image1Url: null,
                        image2Url: null,
                        isCameraDisabled: false,
                        lastPersonTime: null,
                        liveUrl: null,
                        notes: null,
                        recordingStartTime: null,
                        severity: 'INTERMEDIATE',
                        shipEventId: 423421342,
                        shipId: 1,
                        speed: null,
                        startTime: '2023-03-10T06:26:30.706Z',
                        vodHlsUrl: null,
                        vodPath: null,
                        __typename: 'ShipEvent',
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
    },
];
```

**the test:**

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
    useParams: jest
        .fn()
        .mockReturnValue({ shipId: '8', modeId: '2377', cameraId: '12097', shipCameraId: '21' }),
}));
const mocks = [...shipEventsMockQuery, ...shipEventsSubscriptionmock];


function getHookWrapper(mocks = []) {
    const wrapper = ({ children }) => (
        <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
            {children}
        </MockedProvider>
    );
    const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() => useFetchShipEvents({ limit: 10, fleetId: 1 }), {
        wrapper,
    });


    return { result, waitForNextUpdate };
}

describe('shipEvents', () => {
    it('test1', async () => {
        const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = getHookWrapper(mocks);

        await act(async () => {
            result.current.fetchEvents();
            console.log(' ~ file: ShipEventsTest.test.js:61 ~ describe ~ result:', result.current);
            await waitFor(() => expect(result.current.isEventsLoading).toBeTruthy(), {
                timeout: 2000,
            });
        });

        expect(result.current?.shipEvents?.events?.length)?.toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(1);
    });
});
```

thanks for the guidance.